# Getting parsing error when I try to use pgloader from csv to cloud sql for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, pgloader

I am trying to connect a csv file to alloydb (postgres gcp managed database) and I'm getting the following error:

```
2024-03-04T19:21:15.008000Z LOG pgloader version "3.6.7~devel"
2024-03-04T19:21:15.012000Z LOG Parsing commands from file #P"/home/julie_wang/csv_to_postgres.load"
KABOOM!
ESRAP-PARSE-ERROR: At

  
      WITH truncate,
  
      ^ (Line 5, Column 4, Position 191)

In context COMMANDS:

While parsing COMMANDS. Expected:

     the character Tab
  or the character Newline
  or the character Return
  or the character Space
  or the string "--"
  or the string "/*"
  or the string "load"
An unhandled error condition has been signalled: At
```

This is my code.

```
LOAD CSV
    FROM 'path/to/file.csv' ("Site Name", Year, Deaths, Multivitamin)
    INTO postgresql://postgres:password@ipaddress/postgres ("Site Name", Year, Deaths, Multivitamin);

    WITH truncate,
        skip header = 1,
        fields optionally enclosed by '"',
        fields escaped by double-quote,
        fields terminated by ','

        SET client_encoding to 'latin1',
            work_mem to '12MB',
            standard_conforming_strings to 'on'

   BEFORE LOAD DO
    $$ drop table if exists csv; $$,
    $$ create table csv (
        "Site Name" text,
        Year int,
        Deaths int,
        Multivitamin int
       );
  $$;
```

I'm not sure if the issue is due to how I'm calling the connection string to cloud sql or a syntax issue due to pgloader. I don't have a lot of experience with pgloader. If someone has any insights that would be great

Comment: 1) See here [CSV](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/csv.html). There is no `;` after the `INTO`. 2) This could be done in `psql` using `\copy`.